# Need a query to seperate char values and number values from table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table TAB1 which is having one column COL1. as shown below.

TAB1

```
COL1
123
Xyz
CM
44
```

I need single query which will give following output.

```
Ccol  | Ncol
Xyz    | 123
CM    |  45
```

Comment: It's good to show some effort :)

Comment: How exactly do you know that `123` belongs to `Xyz` rather `CM`? Without a column to give order the output will be random. Also, when you say *"single query"* do you mean you need a pure SQL solution?

Comment: This is just an example. There is no any relationship between 123 and xyz if 123 come with CM this is also fine.

Comment: Which column does `3.2` go into? How about `-92`? For extra credit: how about `1E3`? (To understand the last question, run this and try to understand the output: `select 1E3 from dual;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12 you can define a function in a sub-query factoring clause and this can easily determine whether a value is numeric:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COL1) AS 
  SELECT '123'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Xyz'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CM'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '44'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1E3'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-1.2' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH
  FUNCTION isNumeric( value VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    n NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    n := TO_NUMBER( value );
    RETURN 1;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 0;
  END;
SELECT Ccol,
       TO_NUMBER( Ncol ) AS Ncol
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         isNumeric( col1 ) AS isNumber,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY isNumeric( col1 ) ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT ( MAX( Col1 ) FOR isNumber IN ( 0 AS Ccol, 1 AS Ncol ) )
ORDER BY rn
```

**Output**:

> ```
> CCOL | NCOL
> :--- | ---:
> Xyz  |  123
> CM   |   44
> null | 1000
> null | -1.2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4feb6d8bc820ac225fe34e3a4e6ba579)*

In earlier versions you can use `CREATE FUNCTION` rather than defining it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
WITH TAB1(COL1) AS 
(
SELECT '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '44' FROM DUAL
)
-- Actual query starts from here
, CTE AS (SELECT
    COL1,
    NUMERIC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY NUMERIC
        ORDER BY LENGTH(COL1) DESC -- here I considered that Xyz and 123 both have length 3 and are related and same for CM and 44
    ) AS RN
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COL1,
            CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE ( COL1,
                                   '^[[:digit:]]+$' ) THEN 'NUMBER'
                ELSE 'NOT NUMBER'
            END AS NUMERIC
        FROM
            TAB1
    ))
SELECT
    C.COL1   AS "Ccol",
    N.COL1   AS "Ncol"
FROM
    CTE N
    FULL OUTER JOIN CTE C ON ( N.RN = C.RN )
WHERE
    N.NUMERIC = 'NUMBER'
    AND C.NUMERIC = 'NOT NUMBER';
```

Output:

```
Cco Nco
--- ---
Xyz 123
CM  44
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f9bf181bb7cd46baaefa80e4b15b209)

Cheers!!